# Существует ли тип/класс или какой-то подход для работы с Unicode String на С++?

Tags: c++, строки, unicode

Какой тип/класс строки лучше всего использовать для работы в C++ со строками Unicode? Может, есть какой-нибудь общий, эффективный подход?

Думал в сторону wstring, но, заглянув в Википедию, прочитал следующее:

> В Windows API тип wchar_t именуется
> как WCHAR и имеет фиксированный размер
> 16 бит, что не позволяет кодировать
> весь набор символов Unicode (больше 1
> миллиона).

После этого задумался, как же это реализовано в QString:

> QString хранит строку 16-битных QChar,
> где каждому QChar соответствует один
> символ Unicode 4.0. (Символы Unicode
> со значениями кодов больше 65535
> хранятся с использованием суррогатных
> пар, т.е. двух последовательных
> QChar.)

Пишу не на Qt... Как быть?

Comment: Я в c++ использую обычный тип string, настройки кодировки unicode или многобайтовой указываю в настройках компилятора. Проблем вроде не замечал.

Comment: Вы уже наткнулись на ситуацию, когда вам реально понадобились символы вне basic multilingual plane? Если нет, пользуйтесь `wstring`.

Comment: Кстати, в Linux размер wchar\_t 4 байта (UCS-32).

Comment: *"лучше всего"* зависит от приложения. Простой метод -- [хранить все строки в utf-8 (`std::string`, `char*`)](http://utf8everywhere.org/) и преобразовывать по мере необходимости. Вот около [подробный список возможных проблем при работе с Юникодом](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6163129) (ответ о perl, но вещи, относящиеся к Юникоду универсальны).

Comment: Ещё для работы с Unicode есть библиотека ICU: http://site.icu-project.org/ Она является официальной библитекой Unicode в ней все функции реализованы правильно - в полном соответствии со стандартом.